# All fundamental groups are Abelian?

Tags: proof-verification, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

> If $(X, x_0)$ is an H-space, then $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ is Abelian.

I started with knowing I had to shows $[f][g]=[g][f]$, which means showing $f * g \simeq g * f \text{ rel } \{0,1\}$
but I contructed a homotopy from this by partitioning the unit square into $6$ triangles made from  drawing in both diagonals and a vertical line from $(\frac{1}{2}, 1)$ to $(\frac{1}{2}, 0)$, where: LL means lower left triangle, UR means upper right triangle, L means left triangle, etc...

But I realized that I didn't use the fact that the space is an H-space at all.

$F(s,t) =
\begin{cases}
f(2\frac{t-s}{2t-1}),  & \text{if $(s,t)$ in LL} \\
g(\frac{2s-1}{1-2t}), & \text{if $(s,t)$ in LR} \\
x_0,  & \text{if $(s,t)$ in L or R} \\
g(2\frac{1-s-t}{1-2t}), & \text{if $(s,t)$ in UL} \\
f(\frac{1-2s}{1-2t}), & \text{if $(s,t)$ in UR} \\
\end{cases}$

So given this homotopy is continuous (all of its inner functions are continuous since they're all affine maps in their respective domains), what did I assume incorrectly?

Here's the diagram I used:

[image]

Comment: In fact, if this reasoning worked, you would be able to prove that all fundamental groups are _trivial_, simply by using different curves in the upper and lower parts of the diagram.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your $F$ is not continuous at $(s,t)=(\frac12,\frac12)$ -- for example, there are points arbitrarily close to $(\frac12,\frac12)$ where $F$ equals $f(\frac12)$, which is generally some nonzero distance from $x_0$.

You're probably confusing yourself by the fact that the *restriction* of $F$ to any horizontal or vertical *line* is continuous -- but that doesn't mean that $F$ itself is continuous.

Comment: So none of the functions would be continuous then since they all share that discontinuity?  Otherwise I would assume gluing lemma.

Comment: @OliverG: Your parts for LL, LR, UL, UR are not even _defined_ at $(\frac12,\frac12)$, since your expressions would involve dividing by zero when $t=\frac12$. And they can't be extended continuously to that point (unless $f$ and $g$ are constant).